# Загрузка картинок из сети в приложение Android

Tags: java, android, изображения

Интересует вопрос подобной реализации, например: есть картинка на html странице, как мне загрузить её в приложение и показать в ImageView? В программировании новичок, может подскажете ресурсы и либы?

Comment: Universal Image Library , Picasso

Comment: Спасибо большое, а как на счёт статей?

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149 http://habrahabr.ru/post/134186/

Comment: Через Picasso намного быстрее грузит, так что не сказал бы что для ленивых

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Хороший пример с наследованием загрузчика картинки от [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) и определением своего метода [doInBackground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)), взятый с [английского SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android), который взял его с Android Developers, который уже его убрал.

Сам AsyncTask представляет собой реализацию короткого асинхронного запроса для основного GUI потока без необходимости самому ковырятся с потоками.

```
// Показать картинку
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
            .execute("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png");
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, IndexActivity.class));
    finish();

}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Ошибка передачи изображения", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

И в манифесте для приложения нужно конечно же разрешить загрузку:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Если нужно быстро и без всякой асинхронности, обработки ошибок и.т.д.:

```
URL newurl = new URL(image_location_url); 
mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream());
myImageView.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);
```

Для совсем ленивых однострочник на [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/):

```
Picasso.with(context).load(myImageURL).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень полезно, завтра размеру

Comment: А как установить ограничение на время попыток подключения к серверу в данном примере?

Answer (score 2):

Использовать стоит только пример с наследованием загрузчика картинки от `AsyncTask`.   В противном случае может выскакивать ошибка исключения:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

, которая не даст выполнять сетевые запросы в основном потоке.

Не стоит забывать и о `android:usesCleartextTraffic = "true"` в манифесте, если простые запросы по HTTP.